Issue with Pod file build
I've been struggling with building my project on Xcode. Getting errors such as "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" and "/Users/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation/RCTNativeAnimatedTurboModule.mm:18:45 Cannot find protocol declaration for 'NativeAnimatedModuleSpec'" as well as about 20 others, have been debugging for quite some time but want to see if anyone has experienced this and can help.
aic
I've tried uninstalling Xcode completely and reinstalled it connecting back to my project but still getting errors. it's basically saying nothing is connected. errors attached. installed using cocoa pods
